# C# linq database optimization

Tags: c#, database, linq

I have the following C# code:

```
MyObject myObj= dbCtx.MyObjects.FirstOrDefault(
    p => p.Src.AccNum == srcAccNum && p.Dest.AccNum == destAccNum);
```

It executes fine.  However, I would prefer to only query the database if `p.SrcId < p.DestId`

Is this possible and how would I code it?

Comment: Just add it to the predicate

Comment: `&& p.SrcId < p.DestId`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add it to the predicate.

Querying the `DbSet` (or an `IQueryable`) will filter the data directly in database. That is, the predicate will be translated to SQL and just the data which match the predicate will be will be loaded in memory.

```
MyObject myObj = dbCtx.MyObjects.FirstOrDefault(
     p => p.SrcId < p.DestId && p.Src.AccNum == srcAccNum && p.Dest.AccNum == destAccNum);
```

Comment: Thanks, but won't it still be querying the database, just not returning data if the predicate is false?

Comment: @PhilO I think you misunderstood how linq to entities work. Querying the `DbSet` (or an `IQueryable`) will filter the data directly in database. That is, your predicate will be translated to SQL and just the data which match the predicate will be "serialized" to the application.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.